# Search Engine Optimization with a Drop-Down menu

Tags: html, seo, search-engine

I would like to know the best practices concerning the usage of a drop-down menu in my website along with search engine optimization. Currently, the content of the menu uses almost 50% of the HTML code, but doesn't describe at all the real content of the page.

Should I move my menu at the end of the HTML code and replace it visually at the top using CSS? What is the best thing to do?

My website is http://www.meow.fr, you can check the HTML code there.

Comment: I think your dropdown menu is just fine.  It directs the bot to the appropriate page in a nice /UL.

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript and Drop Down Menus**

It is best to keep things simple. Search engines still do not read  JavaScript very well. If your site navigation is based on JavaScript, it will be difficult to get all of your pages indexed. If the decorative drops down type menus are important to you, always provide a back up of plain text links.

Answer (score 0):

In strict terms, your dropdown DOES reflect the real content of your page because it's on that page. You could try moving it lower down with CSS but the SEO effects of this are likely to be negligible. Only testing & waiting & seeing can really tell.

A bigger problem for your page might be mixing English and French content. Ranking may suffer because of this.

Two more important things for that page:

1 - Your page title and H1 aren't anything anyone will search for ("Back in Dali"). A descriptive title such as "Trip to Dali" or "Photos from Dali" would be better.

2 - Add alt texts to your images (not too long) to boost relevant keyword-rich content.